# I am trying to build latest git branch in jenkins but jenkins job is picking old branch

Tags: jenkins

Passing the branch as a parameter. Trying to build /origin/naranja branch but it is building /origin/mango. How do I get to the original state where the selected branch is being built.

Comment: How do you configure the job?

Comment: it is a freestyle project pulling the code using the git plugin